# Unable to find Markup in itextsharp

Tags: itext

Im using iTextSharp ver. 5.4.1.  I am trying to generate PDF from HTML. Below pasted line of code  gives an error **the name 'Markup' does not exist in the current context**. This works fine with itextSharp ver 5.2.1. Can some body tell  **Markup** belongs to which class in ver 5.4.1.

```
 document.Add(new Header(**Markup**.HTML_ATTR_STYLESHEET, string.Empty));
```

code :

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Renders the PDF to an array of bytes
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] RenderPdf()
        {

            //Document is inbuilt class, available in iTextSharp
            MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream();
            Document document = new Document(this.PageSize);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, file);

            //allow modifications of the document
            if (this.BeforeRender is RenderEvent)
            {
                this.BeforeRender(writer, document);
            }

            //header
            document.Add(new Header(Markup.HTML_ATTR_STYLESHEET, string.Empty));
            document.Open();

            //render each page that has been added
            foreach (HtmlPdfPage page in this._Pages)
            {
                document.NewPage();

                //generate this page of text
                MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                StreamWriter html = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);

                //get the page output
                html.Write(string.Concat(HtmlToPdfBuilder.DOCUMENT_HTML_START, page._Html.ToString(), HtmlToPdfBuilder.DOCUMENT_HTML_END));
                html.Close();
                html.Dispose();

                //read the created stream
                MemoryStream generate = new MemoryStream(output.ToArray());
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(generate);
                foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)HTMLWorker.ParseToList(reader, this._Styles))
                {
                    document.Add((IElement)item);
                }

                //cleanup these streams
                html.Dispose();
                reader.Dispose();
                output.Dispose();
                generate.Dispose();

            }

            //after rendering
            if (this.AfterRender is RenderEvent)
            {
                this.AfterRender(writer, document);
            }

            //return the rendered PDF
            document.Close();
            return file.ToArray();

        }
```

Comment: The markup class was removed a long time ago, along with HtmlWriter. Are you trying to create HTML???

Comment: ya. I am trying to generate pdf in .net MVC and came across this code by Hugo Bonacci. could you please direc to a better way to generate pdf from HTML in MVC application.

Comment: I don't know Hugo Bonacci, but if he tells you you need the Markup class to do this, he's wrong. You could for instance read http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-html-to-pdf-using-itext.html

Comment: Thank you. could you please guide me to find a best way to generate PDF in .net MVC application.

Comment: @BumbleBee did you ever find a solution to this issue? I just ran into this problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private const string HTML_ATTR_STYLESHEET = "stylesheet";

document.Add(new Header( HTML_ATTR_STYLESHEET, string.Empty));
```